# Docker container port 80 - "Connection refused"

Tags: docker, curl

**Docker file content -**

[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# cat Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER dhirendra120285.rai@gmail.com
RUN yum update -y && yum install httpd net-tools -y
CMD ["apachectl","-D","FOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 80
```

**Ansible playbook - To create a new docker image -**

```
[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# cat build_docker_image.yml
---
        - name: Build a docker image
          hosts: localhost
          gather_facts: no
          tasks:
                - name: Build a CENTOS (latest) docker image with fully updated and Webservice installed
                  docker_image:
                        path: /root/ANSIBLE/ANSIBLEDOCKER/dockerbuild/
                        name: docker-image-created-by-ansible
                        tag: ansibleexample
...
```

**Checking syntax**

```
[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# ansible-playbook 
build_docker_image.yml --syntax-check

playbook: build_docker_image.yml
```

**Building Docker image using ansible with http installed -**

```
[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# ansible-playbook build_docker_image.yml
```

**Post build - checking images**

```
[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# docker images

REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker-image-created-by-ansible   ansibleexample      622e72211b67        35 minutes ago      449MB
centos                            latest              e934aafc2206        6 weeks ago         199MB
```

**Spinning-up 1st container from 622e72211b67 image -**

```
[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# docker run -it --name httpimage 622e72211b67 bash
```

**Container run status (with port 80 exposed) -**

```
[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
be452b97dda0        622e72211b67        "bash"              7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        80/tcp              httpimage
```

**Getting container IP address -**

```
[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# docker inspect --format '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'  httpimage
172.17.0.2

[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# ping -c2 172.17.0.2

PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.107 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms

--- 172.17.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.058/0.082/0.107/0.026 ms

[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# telnet 172.17.0.2 80
Trying 172.17.0.2...

telnet: connect to address 172.17.0.2: Connection refused

[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# curl http://172.17.0.2:80

curl: (7) Failed connect to 172.17.0.2:80; Connection refused
```

Please suggest what is wrong here?

Thanks,
Dhirendra

Comment: Check your firewall settings

Comment: first check container is in running state "docker ps " , if yes get shell of container using command "docker exec -it container_name bash" and check apache service is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the difference between your first output of `docker ps`:

```
[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
be452b97dda0        622e72211b67        "bash"              7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        80/tcp              httpimage
```

And your second output of the same command:

```
[root@ansiblecontrolnode dockerbuild]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
bfe98153a77a        0f104cab653d        "apachectl -D FOREGR…"   41 seconds ago      Up 40 seconds       80/tcp              httpcontainer
```

On you first attempt you were starting the container with this command:

```
docker run -it --name httpimage 622e72211b67 bash
```

On the second you were using this command:

```
docker run -tid --name httpcontainer 0f104cab653d
```

The result: On the first run you were starting bash instead of apache. The container was running, but apache wasn't running, so you got `Connection refused` when you tried to access it with curl.